# Prevent records from getting updated if there is related case with a record type Complaint

Tags: case, validation

I have a an object . I have created a look up on Case for that object so that it shows the related case with  a complaint record type case . Now I want users to close the case before proceeding to further review or . If I Implement DLRS to get the total no of open cases , its not working . My validation on case doesn't work as well

```
AND 
( 
RecordType.DeveloperName ='Complaint', 
NOT(ISBLANK(TEXT( Status ))), 
TEXT(Status) <> "Closed", 
IsPICKVAL(Scheme_Program__c,"VEET") , 

ISPICKVAL( Job__r.Status ,"For Review")
```

Comment: Hi prathiba. It sounds like you have two independent problems here - one about your DLRS rollup, and one about your validation rule. Can you add some more detail about the specific requirements and how you've implemented this rollup?

Comment: I have a custom object and Case .record type =Complaint ..Look up from case to the custom object shows all related complaint cases . . To get the total no of complaint cases I am using DLRS . Thats not working on one side . I want that count because the record should be sent for review if there are any complaint cases . Inorder to implement the validation on the record I wanted that count .Also on the other side i thought could do a validation on case object .